# Use different display settings for the welcome / logon screen than my desktop? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, resolution, external-display, nvidia-graphics-card

I vaguely recall back in the days of Windows XP that I could set up my display settings as "Administrator" and they would apply to the logon screen.  However, once I log in my user settings could adjust the display settings again.  So, there would be two different resolutions for the desktop versus the login screen.

Is anything like this possible in Windows 7?

Background:

I'm currently having a problem with my system where the full 2560x1440 resolution of my Dell U2711 monitor isn't well supported by my ASUS G73S laptop (it has an NVIDIA GeForce GTX440M CUDA with 1.5GB RAM).  The laptop doesn't have DVI-D or DisplayPort outputs and the monitor doesn't officially support that resolution over HDMI.  So, to work around it I added a "Custom Resolution" in the nvidia control panel. This works until the computer sleeps or reboots, at which point it stops working and the display driver freaks out.  If, however, I get the external monitor to show a lower resolution I can successfully "upgrade" the resolution - I just have to make sure the laptop comes out of sleep using the lower 1920x1080 resolution that is better supported.  Then I can increase that afterwards.